# How do I report bugs to the rails team?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I found a weird bug in Rails 3.0.? that I want to report to the Rails team, but I have no idea how to do it.

Does anyone here know how to do this?  Where is the open source project hosted?  Do they have have ticket system?

Actually, I am going to share the issue I found, maybe it really isn't a bug.  I am using Rails 3.0.7 and Ruby 1.8.7.

I created some static pages and I have two pages that are named very similar one named "holiday" and the other named "holidays".  First, I created the singular "holiday" page and everything worked as it should.  Then I created the plural version of it and when I tried to test it didn't work, I kept getting redirected to the not found or 404.  Just to be clear, yes I restarted the server but that didn't fix the problem.  The only way this weird issue went away in when I cleared the browser cache.

Here are the code snippets.

In the routes I added this:

```
match '/holiday'    => 'pages#holiday'   , :as => 'holiday'
match '/holidays'   => 'pages#holidays'  , :as => 'holidays'
```

in the controller I just added empty actions

```
def holiday(); end
def holidays(); end
```

somewhere in the views folder I have the corresponding pages "holiday.html.erb" and "holidays.html.erb".

When I visit the first page (/holiday) it works.  The page gets served.
When I visit the second page (/hoidays) it doesn't work.  I get redirected to the not found / 404 page.

Has anyone encountered this weird issue in Rails 3?

Comment: I think maybe the `/holidays` link will never match, since `/holiday` will always match on the string `holidays`.

Comment: Once I clear the browser cache it matches and it works, so it makes me think this is a bug.  The route is matching explicitly "holiday" and "holidays".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the bugs/issues system:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues

You can search for the bug before submitting it. Maybe someone already reported it.